# Ubuntu 19.04 on Dell Precision T3400 stops booting at "starting GNOME Display Manager"

Tags: boot, gnome, system-installation, gnome-shell, display-manager

I installed 19.04 but when it restarts off the hard drive it gets to

> starting GNOME Display Manager

and doesn't go any farther.

I have 2 compuers both Dell Precision T3400, one with a dual VGA card and one with a VGA + HDMI card, and I get the same behaviour on both of them.

What could be the problem, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. It looked like it was at the point where the video card would take over. I had originally done an install involving download of 3rd party software. So I tried again without this and found my machine would boot successfully. I think the 3rd party drivers are not so necessary for own machine these days anyway so I will see how I go without them. Your situation may be different, though.

Comment: I was doing a "clean install" to a hard drive.  I added no other software or drivers.  Just never go past the "starting GNOME display manager

Comment: @RichPrim but did you select the option to install 3rd party software during installation? This answer suggests not selecting that option. If you selected it, try reinstalling without selecting it. If you didn't select it, you might want to try booting with nomodeset (press shift when you switch on to get the GRUB menu, press e, add `nomodeset` to the end of the line starting with `Linux`, press F10 to boot) and then looking for proprietary drivers in settings, because it looks like a graphics driver problem

Comment: I found a solution, uncheck the box "update software during installation"

Comment: It appears during install the update is installing a monitor driver that in not comparable with my computer.   After install you can update the software, just don't change the monitor setup. Third party software was not the problem.

Comment: I was wrong so sorry, You are correct it was the 3rd party software.

Comment: I used an old drive and re-ran the install, this time I did not check the 3rd party software and everything worked correctly, sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

try xubuntu, it uses a different display manager.

Comment: Yes I  did load ubuntu mate and that did work